# Tab layout underline width according to tab layout text size

Tags: android, android-tablayout, tabitem

I have Tab layout in which having two TabItems .So when one tabitem is selected the underline is coming from starting point and the width is too big .
So i want to set that indicator width according to my tab text and to show underline only under the text in both tab items.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final  TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.varietytaba);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("VEG"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("NON VEG"));
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_drinka);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new Fragvariety.Pageradapter(getChildFragmentManager(),
            tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
```